# Map a key to another key as keyboard damaged

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

My @ or 2 key is not working. I want to set it like, if user press Alt + a or something the 2 should be inserted to the active window. I have achieved this in windows using Auto It. In ubuntu i saw some solutions but couldn't do it. Any help would be appreciated. Or else i will be forced to move back to windows :-(

Answer (score 2):

First install `xbindkeys` and `xte` by running:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation
```

1. Create the `xbindkeys` configuration file: `xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc`
2. Next we need to edit the file.  Run `gedit .xbindkeysrc`
3. Add this to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   "xte 'key 2'"
   m:0x18 + c:38  
   Alt+Mod2 + a
   ```
4. Save the file.
5. Open "Startup Applications" from the dash, and click "Add".
6. Put `/usr/bin/xbindkeys`  and click "Add".
7. Restart the computer.

Your <kbd>2</kbd> key should now be bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the program "Xmodmap"? Look at the documentation and if something is unclear ask again. Btw, a new keyboard shouldn't be to expensive...

Comment: Its my friends laptop, and she can't afford a orginal keyboard for atleast next few months.